# My h tags and columns alignment become an issue as I shrink the screen size

Tags: css

I have become very frustrated using CSS in trying to fix one page's section. Specifically, I have a section with a few h tags and some columns (sample shown below). I have tried many things with CSS, including:

- centering the tags,
- using 'rem' for the font-size, and
- I've tried making the columns width a percentage of the viewport.

Ultimately, what I need is for the text to shrink when I change screen size, and the tags to stay positioned above the columns and remain centered; also – ideally – the columns would not wrap (but if they do then they should be centered)

```html
<div class="encompasing-div-class">
  <h5>Small Tag</h5>
  <div class="row">
    <h3 class="mobile-only">column tag</h3>
    <div class="column">
      <ul>
        <li> things</li>
        <li> things </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h3 class="mobile-only">column tag</h3>
      <ul>
        <li> more things </li>
        <li> more things </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row{ 
   text-align: center;
   font-size: .8rem;
}

.column{
   justify-content: center;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: .8rem;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I suck at this stuff but I'm trying my hardest. I'm sure someone will let me know if I left some information out. Thank you all.

Below, I have added an image of what my issue is so it is clear as can be.
[image]

Comment: Can you add your CSS too please?

Comment: Also, your HTML is missing quite a few closing tags.

Comment: If you want the text to shrink with the viewport then try making font size related to viewport width - but be wary of it getting too small/unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example.
I've moved one h3 tag into the `.column` div. I've used `display:flex` to position each column side by side. We use `flex:1` to make the columns equal width (for an explanation why, see [this article](https://css-tricks.com/equal-columns-with-flexbox-its-more-complicated-than-you-might-think/) on css tricks).

To stop your text wrapping, I've set the text to `white-space:nowrap` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) for details).

To get the text to grow and shrink to the screen size you can use [viewport units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/) but obviously if your screen is too large or too small you'll end up with tiny or giant font sizes so we limit these using `clamp()` (again, CSS tricks has a good [article](https://css-tricks.com/min-max-and-clamp-are-css-magic/) on this). Annotated code below:

```css
body {
  background-color: #222222;
  color: #fefefe;
}

.row {
  display: flex; /* make the column elements appear side by side using flexbox */
}
.column {
  white-space: nowrap;  /*stop the text from wrapping */
  flex: 1; /* make each column 50% of the parent */
  font-size: clamp(0.75rem, 4vw, 1.5rem); /* make the font size 4% of the viewport width but never go above 1.5rem or below 0.75rem */
}
.mobile-only {
  text-align: center; /* self-explanatory */
}
```

```html
<div class="encompasing-div-class">
  <h5>Small Tag</h5>
  <div class="row">
    <!-- moved this below <h3 class="mobile-only">column tag</h3> -->
    <div class="column">
      <h3 class="mobile-only">column tag</h3>
      <ul>
        <li> things</li>
        <li> things </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h3 class="mobile-only">column tag</h3>
      <ul>
        <li> more things </li>
        <li> more things </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
        <div class="column">
      <h3 class="mobile-only">column tag</h3>
      <ul>
        <li> more things </li>
        <li> more things </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're very welcome Patrick. 